# What is the best asp.net mvc code example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are quite a few asp.net mvc code examples by different people at www.asp.net/mvc, based on your experience, what is the best code example, I mean, the example you can learn and follow mostly in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CodeBetterCanvas - Learning Application for ASP.NET MVC](http://code.google.com/p/codebettercanvas/) seems like something you can use directly in your own project, or get some good design ideas from.

The homepage describes it as "*A project to help developers get started with their own MVC project. The goal is to showcase best-practices while providing something tangible to start from. The code is intentionally light on features in order to be used as-is in a new project.*"

**Highlights:**

- Developed around SOLID principles
- NInject is aggressively used
- NHibernate, Linq to NHibernate and FluentNHibernate
- jQuery
- Unit tests

Answer (score 4):

To get started with ASP.NET MVC, I suggest looking at the project template itself (which helps **a lot** at the beginning) first and then use the [NerdDinner tutorial by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx).

To learn more, I don't really think tutorial style things will help. Personally I start digging into frameworks myself after the initial spark (the VS IntelliSense menu is a great help, by the way ;) )

Comment: +1, agree that NerdDinner is a great tutorial to learn the framework